# Mosaico not displaying images in editor

Tags: mosaico

When using Mosaico to build an email, I'm never seeing images in the editor - they display when sending tests or real emails, and when previewing the email, but in the editor they appear as a small blue square with a question mark. Has anyone encountered similar, and found a solution?

We're running CiviCRM 5.27.2 in Wordpress.

Update: some more info was requested in the comments. We're running Mosaico 2.4.1592820024 and this is all a recent install. When I check the "network" tab in developers there are indeed two 403 errors which come up when I launch the Mosaico editor, one I think for the image I'm trying to include, and one to wss://public-api.wordpress.com - I can't obviously identify any problems with the Resource URL settings, but guessing that's where the problem/solution lies! Any help is much appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a misconfigured Resource URL.  Can you open your browser's Dev tools (press "F12"), go to the Network tab, then try replicating your issue?  If you get any lines that show anything that's not a "200" status response, you've found your problem.  If the answer is obvious, great; if not, update your question with that info and someone should be able to help!

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include your Mosaico extension's version?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've added more information in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a 403 error on the image, that's not a Resource URL error but a file permission error.

- Right-click the line with the image that isn't loading and select "Open in New Tab".  Reloading this new tab will make it quicker to test changes.
- Check the following (report back here if necessary):
- The user that your web server runs under;
- The user PHP runs as (if it's different);
- The owner of the file that's not loading;
- The file permissions of the file that's not loading.
- Also check for any .htaccess files in the image folder or any parent folders, and your web server logs.

Between these, you should find your problem.  Be mindful that there's both the immediate problem to fix, and also the root cause that led to this situation.

The file owner is going to be your PHP user, but the web server user is the one accessing it.  So either a) they're different users (which is OK, but makes the other variables above relevant) or b) there's a .htaccess file in place.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'll contact the compnay that hosts our website and ask about all this, but hopefully it will fix it. Cheers!